# Easy Way to specify a large amount of rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

If I wanted to make a CSS grid with two columns of equal width, I would do

display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

But now lets say I wanted to make 100 columns of equal length, how would I do that without typing 1fr 100 times.

Comment: Use the [repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat()) function: `repeat(100, 1fr)`

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

use the repeat function: `repeat(100, 1fr)`.